# How do I change my Python interpreter in Enthought Canopy?

Tags: python, ide, pygame, interpreter, canopy

The interpreter with which Canopy is configured on my computer does not have PyGame (which is giving me a lot of grief - I keep getting a 'not responding' error on PyCharm, so am intending to try it with a different IDE), and I'd like to change the interpreter it uses to one with Pygame - but am unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: can you post your code ? otherwise nobody could help you

Comment: Look up docs fror venv on canopy: http://blog.enthought.com/general/venv-in-python-2-7-and-how-it-simplifies-life/

Answer (score 0):

To your original issue (running Pygame in Canopy), you can install PyGame in Canopy Python following these guidelines: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

(tl;dr -- open a Canopy Command Prompt or Canopy Terminal from the Tools menu and type `pip install pygame`)

To your immediate question -- changing the interpreter used by Canopy is not currently supported. It will be supported in the Canopy GUI in a forthcoming version (currently targeted for version 2.2).